# 30A Relay resets Atmega8A MCU as it engages. Are these PCB layouts to blame?

Tags: arduino, avr, relay, opto-isolator

I am designing a PCB that uses an **ATMega8A** MCU to switch two high power relays (***Songle SLA-12VDC-SL-A***). I have used 2 separate approaches with the same disappointed result: the ATmega8A will reset as soon as either of the relay engages, even with no external load.

To eliminate the possibility of EMI caused by the relays’ coil, I have done an experiment with the same setting using an external Arduino UNO powered by the 5V from the PCB. The result is the same: the UNO resets even when it’s like 50cm (1.5 feet) from the relays.

So I reason that it may be because of the power supply, but I have used the LM2576-5V in many project and it’s very reliable. Also ground paths of the signal side and the relay side are separated. 12V and 5V power lines are also separated. Please see the photos.

**Approach 1**: use Optos to isolate the relays and switch them by a transistor

**Approach 2**: like 1 but the opto+transistors switch smaller relays (Songle SLA-05VDC-SL-A) which in turn switch the big 30A relays.

So I am at my wit’s end as to how to use these 30A relays. I saw some commercial relay module that use the same relay and though I don’t have the schematic, I can see that they just use an opto and a transistor, just like in my first approach. Or is it the ATmega8A to blame? I remember hearing somewhere that it’s very sensitive to noise.

I’d appreciate any advice!

Dave

**UPDATE 1**

Please see the complete Eagle schematic and board for both approaches here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_JjLISYz2JHM0t4SzBaQkhZUEE

**UPDATE 2**

I have added the schematics in PNG for your reference.

**UPDATE 3**
Attached is my re-design incorporating your advice so far. Here are the changes:
- Since I don't use the 5V relays to switch the 12V relays anymore, I shrank the board to fit a smaller enclosure
- No more optos, the relays are switched by BJTs connected to MCU
- BJTs resistor value has been changed to 470R
- BJTs are close to their respective diode and the coils' pins
- More ground vias
- Added a 100nF at the AVCC pin of the Atmega8A
- There are 2 separate pairs of GND planes: the upper pair (top & bottom) is for 12V and the lower pair is for signal. They meet at the point where battery GND is connected
- BJTs' emiters are now part of the 12V GND plane

Please let me know if you have any further advice, before I have this fabricated and see how it goes. THANKS!

[image: Approach 1]

[image: Approach 2]

[image: Relay]
[image]
[image]

**NEW DESIGN**
[image]

Comment: Few comments: 1) there's no point of using an optocoupler if you then share the grounds 2) 1kOhm  base resistor might be too high for the 185-mA coil current, to achieve a good saturation 3) put the BJT on the top part of the board (i.e. where the diodes are), so that the emitter current won't flow in the very thin blue GND track on the left side... 4) Just as a double check: did you mount the diodes correctly (i.e. as shown in the layout) ? Can you post a picture of your board too?

Comment: @next-hack 1) point taken 2) I take note, but also see that the 30A relays do engage smoothly 3) yes you can see that the BJTs are SMD mounted on top. I made that GND trace small because I thought the coil current flow was just about 85mA as I remember from the datasheet 4) I am very sure that diodes are mounted correctly, we double checked. I can post an actual pix on Mon as the board is at work

Comment: Time to attach a scope and measure things

Comment: Please provide complete schematic (especially the power supply of the Atmega and reset pullup).

Comment: @filo: I have edited the question to include eagle files for both approaches

Comment: Ground layout looks bad, not enoughvias between top ground and bottom ground, also where are the decoupling caps? Please post a schematic.

Comment: Measure 5V and reset with an oscilloscope while switching the relay. Make sure to use shortest possible ground path for the probe.

Comment: @Dave I wasn't meaning the top layer. I was referring to the top part of the figure. I.e. where diodes are. The BJTs are in the top layer, but they are (in the picture) below the relay).

Also, please post a png of the schematics: not everybody has Eagle (or is willing to install it)

Comment: @peufeu: I have tried adding ground vias by drilling though, and soldering a in decoupling cap at the 12V in to no avail. I also put a 10uF cap at the 12V pin of the LM2576-5V too. I have updated the question with schematics in PNG

Comment: @next-hack: I see. Have added schematics in PNG

Comment: SMPS layout isn't very good, take into account the loops on the switching node. Use planes instead of traces. The diode, inductor and cap should be as close as possible. Also, your crystal shouldn't be that far from the MCU, but as close as possible. You should really take a look into some reference designs on some datasheets.

Comment: In addition to Wesley Lee's comment, you're using only one 100nF decoupling cap, but there are three power pins (AVCC powers PORTC).

Comment: @next-hack There is also a 10uF aluminum cap next to the 100nF. I am redesigning a new board incorporating all your advice. I am adding another 100nF on the AVCC pin. Will post it and I hope to receive your kind review

Comment: @next-hack: Based on your comments, I have made a new re-design as attached. Please do you think there are further issues to look into?

Comment: D4 is so far from the inductor, connected by a thin trace. The inductor is just besides the crystal, which is still far from the MCU. You have more bypass caps, but the connection is still through long-ish traces and then to inexistant planes. The vias you are using are so large, you have barely any space left for proper planes/traces. Look at page 3 on [this](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/snva021c/snva021c.pdf) pdf, it has a nice comparison of good vs bad layout for SMPS. I'm focusing on power supply but the principles should work for the rest as well.

Comment: Also, before trying to "solve" the design, you should really measure some things and find where the fault is coming from. As you said, even with an external arduino (not that the arduino layout is very good but anyway) you are having issues.

Comment: I second Wesley Lee. By the way I noticed you placed the BJTs in the same layer, but "under" the through hole diodes (which are unnecessarily huge by the way - 3A. An 1N4148 would sustain the flyback current easily), that's not really a good practice.

Comment: @Wesley Lee : I take note of your kind comments. Will study the datasheet more carefully & PCB layout and redesign this thing. I may also change to the XL4005 regulator. Will study both. Will keep you updated!

Comment: @next-hack : please see last comment. I take note of the 1N4148 too!